# Compare times on separate dates in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I have 3 different `TimeWithZone` objects:

```
from = Mon, 20 Apr 2020 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
to = Mon, 20 Apr 2020 23:59:59.000000000 UTC +00:00

event = Sat, 01 Jan 2000 07:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

I don't care about the dates. All I need is to be able to see if the time of `event` falls within the time bounds of `from` and `to`.

In the example above, the event *does* fall within the time bounds.

I've tried converting the `from` and `to` to just their time values using `strftime` and then converting them back to times with `#to_time`, but this causes the hours and minutes to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Mon, 20 Apr 2020 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00` is not a valid Ruby expression, you can't assign like that (it gives a syntax error). You should take the time to write a valid example.

Comment: Besides, your example would probably be more interesting if you pick `from` and `to` values that allow event to also be outside that range (they span the entire day right now). Maybe give some more positive / negative example events and edge cases (event right on bound, subsecond differences).

Comment: @Stefan -- #seconds_since_midnight ended up working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format every value and than compare them

```rb
from_time, to_time, event_time = [from, to, event].map { |t| t.strftime("%H%M%S%N") }

event_time.between?(from_time, to_time)
```

Another option - compare just seconds (as `Float`)

```
from_sec, to_sec, event_sec = [from, to, event].map(&:seconds_since_midnight)

event_sec.between?(from_sec, to_sec)
```

Comment: This works quite well! But do you know why `t.strftime("%H%M%S%N")` formats `"2023-04-20T23:59:59.000Z"` as `"065959000000000"`? This doesn't look right.

Comment: What can be done about this edge case? I need 23:59:59 to work.

Comment: You could also compare numerically by calculating the number of seconds, e.g. `map { |t| t.hour * 3600 + t.min * 60 + t.sec }` (and optionally `+ t.subsec` if you need subsecond precision)

Comment: @Stefan ActiveSupport has `seconds_since_midnight` for this :)